# Eclipse doesn't rebuild project after .h file changed

Tags: c++, build, linker, eclipse-cdt

After change of `.h` header file and `ctrl+b` Eclipse doesn't rebuild project, `clean`+`build` helps, but this is very annoying, because I need to wait whole project rebuilt, but need only one `.o` file (or maybe also it's dependencies?) rebuild.

Is there any way to fix that problem?

My enviroment is Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse `Version: 3.8.1`.

**UPDATE:**

Seems it's a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375800